# ios 5 possible to have your app run in the background to fetch data?

Tags: multithreading, ios5

With iOS 5 is it possible to keep the app running in the background even if the user has switch to another app? I'd like my app to keep fetching data and if the data has changed to notify the user.

Is this possible? or it is still only one app at a time is active and all app in background are suspended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only specific apps are allowed to run in the background, according to a document on the iOS developer library on multitasking.

1. Apps that play audible content, while in the background.
2. Apps that keep the user informed of their location at all times.
3. Apps that support VoIP.
4. Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content.
5. Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories, such as bluetooth.

If your application doesn't meet these then it isn't allowed.

There are also various rules about what to do when put in the background.

So, I expect it does rapid switching, but you can have more than one application running, with strict limitations and requirements if you are in the background.

Comment: so my app is updating my local db from data fetch through a webservice. So it means it cannot be run in the background? How does app like facebook notify the user of something written on their wall, is this throught the APNs??. Basically i wanted the app to run in the background to fetch data, when the data changes, to notify the user so he can switch back to my app .... the only way for would be through APNs??? since it cant run in the background?

Comment: @pdiddy - push notifications may be your safest best, which is better for the phone anyway, as you are not having it do useless polling for changes.